# Windows Mobile 6 Forms some part remaining after close

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I developed an app on Windows Mobile 6.5 with c# .
When I try to exit application some part(upper part of the form) of the form remains over the screen. And I can only make it disappear by resetting the device.

First Picture : before closing the application
Second Picture : after closing the application

What should I do in order to completely remove all parts of the form?

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/189/13785191.png/]

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/98795567.png/]

Comment: Edited to show pictures.

Answer (score 2):

you have written a full screen application and used possibly code to move the form etc to make it fullscreen. The official way to have a fullscreen form is to use SHFullScreen API (although it is buggy for the start icon and menu bar, see my blog).

To let WM653 know that you have covered the status bar, you may first make your form not covering the task bar before you exit the application.
You may also issue a ShowWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), SW_NORMAL) before you exit the application.

But, as Kobunite said, the issue may also happen, when your app does not exit normally but more or less crashes before exit and normal cleanup. You may add some debug log in your exit code to see which function or code fails.

Comment: To add to @Kobunite and this answer, you could also get this if the code calls `Application.Exit()` instead of the `Close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with WM6.5.

I work with devices that use WM6.5 and in my experience this only happens when the application is exited incorrectly, uncleanly or suddenly. When I exit the application properly nothing is overlayed where as when the application exits suddenly (i.e. by an unhandled crash, or by stopping the debugger I have the same result as you are reporting.

To stop it happening you'll need to make sure that you are exiting the program cleanly, otherwise this will persist.